# How can I open an application for .txt in java (regardless of operating system )?

Tags: java, text, command-line, operating-system

I should open a .txt file on my java application, so i've searched a way to do this but what i've found is only java calls to operating system, writing console commands. There is a way to open a .txt file independently of operating system of the user?
Note that I want to open an application that reads .txt, not only its content! I'm wondering if there is a way to call default application for reading .txt, without write for example "notepad myTxt.txt" on console from java :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to read a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file)

Comment: That's very different than how your question reads. I recommend that you update "edit" your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Desktop.open()`

From the Javadocs:

> *Launches the associated application to open the file.*

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)

An alternative (because you mentioned "editing") might also be `Desktop.edit()`

Answer (score 0):

You'll most likely want to use:
`FileReader` and `BufferedReader` classes that work on any platform that Java supports. In fact, because Java runs on a virtual machine, simple IO is inherently platorm, OS independent. See [this reference](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/read_a_textfile_in_java.html) for ideas.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I didn't mean this! I've made my question clearer than before!